# Action class is not appended in the URL after form submit in IE11 windows10

Tags: javascript, html, forms, internet-explorer, ie11-developer-tools

I have submitted the  form in Onclick event using javascript in popup. But After Submitting the form the URL came without action class so my pop up is shown blank. I have mimic the form and javascript of  form and JavaScript in the below for your reference.Can anyone help me. this issue is occurred only in IE 11 in windows 10. If I work with IE11 in windows 7 it works fine.I installed IE11 in my windows 10. checked in Edge faced same issue. SubmitFormC is triggered by click Event. Actually Its an search operation after I entered the text in search box. I clicked the search icon. From there my SubmitFormC method is called.

After submitting the form please find the url's in Windows10 and Windows7

```
 (Win 10) -- URL : http://localhost:7001/sample/
  (Win 7)  -- URL : http://localhost:7001/sample/saveaction?typeID=123
```

> Form

```
<form name="submitForm" action="/sample/saveaction.do" method="post">
```

> JavaScript:

```
     function SubmitFormC(Id) {
       document.forms[0].action = "saveaction.do?typeID="+Id;
       document.forms[0].submit();
    }
```

Comment: what do real browsers do (Chrome, Firefox, Edge)?

Comment: in Edge also I faced the same Error, in Chrome page is idle cant able to navigate futher. I have installed IE11 in my windows 10.

Comment: `in Chrome page is idle cant able to navigate futher` - seems an odd statement, but as you haven't shown any indication of how `SubmitFormC` is executed, I can only speculate - any errors in the browser developer tools console? `I have installed IE11 in my windows 10` of course you have, otherwise you wouldn't have the issue with IE11 in windows 10 - seems an odd statement to make, since IE11 is usually installed when installing Windows 10

Comment: SubmitFormC is triggered by click Event. Actually Its an search operation after I entered the text in search box. I clicked the search icon. From there my SubmitFormC method is called.

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - it's a bit difficult with form submission, but at least to show your *program flow*